# When will a browser throw $.ajaxSetup is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert following snippet in my JSP file

```
{
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        async: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "loading data please wait...";
    var loadUrl = "abc.jsp";

    $("#seoarea").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, {
        param1: holdvalue1,
        param2: holdvalue2
    });
}
```

While running this on mozilla firefox its throwing "$.ajaxSetup  is not a function" error.

Comment: Most likely cause is that this code appears before jQuery is included on the page. Wait, no that's not right. In that case, `$` should be undefined as well, and you should see a different error `(ReferenceError)` on `$` instead of on `ajaxSetup`, unless `$` has been defined by some other code before your `ajaxSetup` code, and then jQuery comes, or jQuery is not included at all.

Answer (score 16):

It also can happen if you are using slim version of the library. Slim version does not include ajax.

Go here to get the latest version: https://code.jquery.com/

Credits go to Gus: [TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 7):

This error could happen if you forgot to reference the jQuery library in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For newest version, check this link: https://code.jquery.com/

It could also happen if you are using other js libraries such as [prototypejs](http://www.prototypejs.org/) which also use the `$` function and there could be a conflict. If this is the case you may take a look at [this article](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: +1 - But please uses the latest version in examples! It's 1.4.2 currently, several bug fixes in there.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still not fixed after adding a new version of CDN. There might be somewhere Slim version linked. Check your footer carefully.