# TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm attempting to create an AJAX request. Here's my function definition:

```
function AJAXrequest(url, postedData, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: postedData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Here's where I call it, providing the parameters:

```
AJAXrequest('voting.ajax.php', data, function(data) {
    // function body
});
```

Yet the callback does not run, and instead I get a `console.error`:

```
TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function.
```

Why?

Comment: whether jquery is included

Comment: change this $.ajax() ({ to $.ajax({

Comment: You called `$.ajax` without arguments (`$.ajax()`) and the return value is a jqXHR object, which is not a function. Hence `$.ajax()(...)` will throw an error.

Comment: either you missed to include jquery.js OR you have included jquery.js below the function call OR please try jQuery.ajax (replace $ with jQuery).

Comment: In my case, it's because I used [slim minified](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js) version of JQuery which takes out ajax function

Comment: THANK YOU, Tom Ng. That was exactly the problem I was having. Sadly, the information provided when trying to decide between which version of jQuery to link to, they make no mention of this.

Comment: Also thanks TomNg, it was the slim minified version causing the problem and based on the positive votes from the non accepted answer below it looks like it's the same issue that most people are having.

Comment: This question should really be clarified… The issue is the extra `()` after `$.ajax`. The error means that `$.ajax()` is not a function, because _it really isn’t_. `$.ajax()` is an _object_, not a function. `$.ajax` however _is_ a function. If it wasn’t, the error would say _“`TypeError`: `$.ajax` is not a function”_. _That_ would’ve been caused by importing jQuery Slim, rather than the regular one. Read the error _carefully_! And if jQuery wasn’t imported at all, the error would say _“`ReferenceError`: `$` is not defined”_. The question should mention that the full jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Can confirm 2 years later @TomNg, I'm using Bootstrap 4 which does include jQuery, but only the slim version. Changed my include logic to replace the `slim.min` version with just `min`. Thanks

Comment: Can confirm answer is still relevant on October 2022, @TomNg

Comment: I think you are using the  jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) some ware else, check the bottom line close to </html> tag, Delete that <script> and add new line

Answer (score 1377, accepted):

Neither of the answers here helped me. The problem was: **I was using the slim build of jQuery**, which had some things removed, ajax being one of them.

The solution: Just download the regular (compressed or not) version of jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery) and include it in your project.

Comment: This is what fixed my problem! What the heck jQuery?? Why is `$.ajax` removed from the "slim" build?

Comment: Slim build claimed another victim.

Comment: I copied the code from Bootstrap. They use the slim version. Maybe you too?

Comment: This is documented on the jquery download page, but not on the bootstrap starter template page -- at least not that I saw. Your solution fixed my problem.

Comment: this answer is still useful in September 13 2020 haha! another up-vote from East Africa!

Comment: This answer is _not_ the problem that the question ran into. Given the code in the question, the full build of jQuery would not work either. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271266/1202830) for the real problem here. (Yes, you do need the full build of jQuery, not the slim build, but the real problem is the extra `()`.)

Comment: Slim build is trash, don't use it, it gives so many problems... just stay with the minified, it's already enough! Thanks Gus for the save btw. upvoted

Comment: Using the min build that includes Ajax will be a much better solution for most people, considering file size.  See @Daniel Mendoza answer below

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the weird thing for me is, $.ajax worked fine when my app was running on ColdFusion. Now that I'm running it on Lucee, I'm getting the '$.ajax is not a function' error even though the jquery files didn't change. Switching it out for the non-slim version solved the issue :-)

Comment: 2022 and slim is still missing it

Comment: 2022 again and this saved me!  What heck jquery!!

Comment: Next time, use XMLHttpRequest rather than jQuery

Comment: very help full do same mistake

Answer (score 176):

Double-check if you're using full-version of jquery and not some slim version.

I was using the jquery cdn-script link that comes with jquery. The problem is this one by default is slim.jquery.js which doesn't have the `ajax` function in it. So, if you're using (copy-pasted from Bootstrap website) slim version jquery script link, use the full version instead.

That is to say use
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">` 
instead of
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"`

Comment: Using the min build that includes Ajax will be a much better solution for most people, considering file size.  See @Daniel Mendoza answer below

Answer (score 27):

Not sure, but it looks like you have a syntax error in your code. Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: postedData,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: callback
});
```

You had extra brackets next to `$.ajax` which were not needed. If you still get the error, then the jQuery script file is not loaded.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. The return value was just expected to be a function which it is not.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So really, this problem is just a missing jQuery script file reference really.

Comment: No. Look at it as `$.ajax()();`. This is valid JavaScript. It means "call `$.ajax` and whatever it returns, call it as well". But `$.ajax` does not return a function (which could be called), it returns a `jqXHR` object, so it throws an error. Your answer is correct, the additional `()` are the problem, but the description of the problem is not correct (it's not a syntax error, well at least not for the parser).

Comment: No, sorry, that's what I was stating in my previous comment; that this is not a syntax error problem, since the syntax is valid, but rather an issue with the jQuery script file not loaded at the time $.ajax() is used.

Comment: No, jquery.js is not missing (if it was the error would be about the `$`) but it's not a syntax error either in that it's valid JS. It's just not appropriate syntax for the desired behaviour, so it causes a runtime error as explained by Felix.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have made this clearer. The file is (probably) there, otherwise the error would be something like "Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined".

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

The jQuery file is definitely there.

Answer (score 11):

Reference the jquery min version that includes ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I used following version of jQuery and it worked

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the **slim** build of jQuery, which doesn't have the ajax function in it. Use the **minified** version instead from https://releases.jquery.com/

**Note:**  Make sure to not use the jquery link copied from the Bootstrap website, because they use the slim version.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old posting -- and Gus basically answered it.
But in my experience, JQuery has since changed their code for importing from the CDN - so I thought I would go ahead and post their latest code for importing from the CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error as you have placed parenthesis after ajax function and another set of parenthesis to define the argument list:-

As you have written:-

```
$.ajax() ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: postedData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback
});
```

The parenthesis around ajax has to be removed it should be:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: postedData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap html template remember to remove the link to jquery slim at the bottom of the template.

Answer (score 2):

1. It may be because of the slim build of JQuery. Try to use 'uncompressed' or 'minified' builds. ([JQuery CDNs](https://releases.jquery.com))
2. It also may be because of loading Bootstrap CDN before the JQuery CDN. In my case, I removed the Bootstrap CDN and move the JQuery one to the end of the 'body' tag and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your AJAX function, too much brackets, try instead `$.ajax({`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same question, and my solution was: add the JQuery script.

Especially, we should make sure the corresponding JQuery is loaded when we debug our js under the firefox/chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to run this in **nodejs**: It won't work out of the box, since jquery needs a browser (or similar)! I was just trying to get the import to run and was logging `console.log($)` which wrote `[Function]` and then also `console.log($.ajax)` which returned `undefined`. I had no `tsc` errors and had autocomplete from intellij, so I was wondering what's going on.

Then at some point I realised that `node` might be the problem and not typescript. I tried the same code in the browser and it worked. To make it work you need to run:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

(credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032/3022127)

Answer (score 0):

I included bootstrap scripts and the first one(jquery.slim) is the reason of this error. Removing the first row solved my problem.
[image: error-img]

Answer (score -2):

let me share my experience:

my html page designer use:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

when I create a simple AJAX request, getting an error it says, 
TypeError: $.ajax(…) is not a function

So, i add:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

then, it perfectly works for me at least.

Comment: No. Loading jQuery slim and then immediately **overwriting** it with jQuery is utterly pointless and a waste of bandwidth.