# $.Ajax is not a function during combo box selection change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the Code. I've already researched about it and so far, haven't found the right solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{%static 'javascript/jquery-3.1.1.js'%}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#itemid").change(function(){
    var itemid = $(this).val();
    var func_url = '/get_itemdetails/' + itemid +'/';
    $.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url: func_url,
     dataType:"json",
     success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
     }
    });
   });
  });
  
 </script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, try the `fail` callback and see what the error. `$` is global should not have this issue. Check `$` inside your console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function

Comment: not all versions of jquery come with $.ajax function. Search in your version to see if it has it.

Comment: it is working. i tried this window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
} and it loads properly.

Comment: Could be another library is assigning the `$` variable. Try changing your first line to `jQuery(function($) {`

Comment: already tried it also. still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the latest script header for Google's hosted CDN which allows for the $.ajax Function:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#itemid").change(function(){
    var itemid = $(this).val();
    var func_url = '/get_itemdetails/' + itemid +'/';
    $.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url: func_url,
     dataType:"json",
     success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
     }
    });
   });
  });
  
 </script>
```

Comment: @Bigboss no problem, I'm glad we could get it figured out!