# posting input data from html to python script with ajax

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am wanting to POST a user inputted data in an html file to a Python script with AJAX and have the Python script return it so that it shows up in a specific div in the html file.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AJAX Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function test()
        {
            var message = $('input[name=message]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/cgi-bin/hello.py",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"text" : message},
                success: function(response){
                        $("#div").html(response);
                }
            });
        };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
    Enter Message: <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()">
    </form>
    <div id="div">Default Message</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Python

```
#!/home/user/virtualenv/test/3.5/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable() 

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print data
```

When I type a message into the input box and press the submit button, nothing happens.  I am new to this so I feel like I am probably not understanding how this works.  Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:  Console is showing `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

Edit 2: The first problem was due to using the slim version of jquery.  After fixing that, nothing is happening on the page when I input and click submit.

Comment: Look at the developer console for certain javascript errors, and also make sure that your python endpoint is setup correctly. Not sure what you are using for http server.

Comment: I am trying to set up the page on a webhost and I believe python is setup correctly.  In console, I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

Comment: It appears that you did not include JQuery library in the header. Also check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function You should definitely be Googling before asking questions.

Comment: Thank you, I have the jquery script source in the header but it doesn't seem to work.  I will try to figure it out.  Regarding the googling, I would have googled it if I knew about the developer console that you told me about.  Without the console, I had no idea what was going on.  So, thank you twice.

Comment: after fixing the jquery issue, nothing happens when I input and press submit

Comment: when you check the console after submitting, do you see the network traffic? Do you see the request being sent? If so what is the http response?

Comment: @Hozikimaru it shows that it is using GET and the url shows the query string `?message=whateverityped` at the end

Comment: I changed the input button to `<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>` and now it is POSTing the data, but I am not getting the correct data to show up in the div.  Instead, I am getting `FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('text', 'blahblah')])`.  I think I saw something about this while researching so I will go ahead and search for it again.  Thank you for all of your help so far!

Comment: @Hozikimaru I have figured it out, I had to access the value by using `print (data["text"].value)` in python.  thank you for everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the form was submitting when I clicked the button.  The solution was to change the input type to `<button value="Submit" onclick="test()">`.

The next problem was that python was returning `FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('text', 'blahblah')])`.  The solution was to access the value by using `print (data["text"].value)`