# jquery ajax error and debugging. $ajax is not a function

Tags: ajax

[image]

I want to send checked values to server.
The checkboxes are categorized by three category
1. name= fields
2. name= tasktypes
3. name= lifestyles
I success to get checked values each of category
and save the values to list named fileds, tasktypes, lifestyles.

when I send this lists to server,
$ajax. is not a function error occured.
and error: define is not work.

what is the reason?
and how can I debug this ajax module?
[image]

Comment: Try jQuery.ajax() method instead of $.ajax. See if that works

Comment: Or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function

Comment: not work. same error yet..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function)