# i want to get data form database using ajax, but it doesn't work. what should i change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to get data form database using ajax, but it doesn't work. what should i change?

```
function getdata()
    {
        alert();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type:'post',
            url:'view.php', 
            data:{
                num: "num",
                name : "name", 
                univ : "univ",
                ex: "ex",
                line : "line"
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
                // if (response!=""){
                //  $("#table").html(response);
                // }
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is the button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="getdata()" value="Submit"/>
```

the error called "ajax is not a function". thank you

Comment: Do you include jquery? There is no PHP in this question. Also just sending strings in the AJAX request doesnt seem to useful.

Comment: if i use form action, it work. so, i don't think the problem is in the php. but i can't use form 'cause i want to show it at the same page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: `$.ajax` is not native JS, it is jquery. You need to include the library.

Comment: i've include jquery, but still didn't work

Comment: Same error message?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you make the same request with a tool such as [postman](https://www.postman.com/)?

We're going to need a little more context to form be helpful.

Comment: No additional context is needed. There is no PHP or POST processing occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

A little demo to show that it basically works once you include jQuery:

```js
function getdata()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type:'post',
        url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 
        data:{
            num: "num",
            name : "name", 
            univ : "univ",
            ex: "ex",
            line : "line"
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
if (response!=""){
 
 $("#out").html(JSON.stringify(response));
}
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="getdata()" value="Submit"/>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```