# There is something wrong with my AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wrote the following code where i have bootstrap nav with two menu items and then i have some javascript code with ajax request:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test page</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container user-profile">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item" id="p">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="edp">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Edit profile</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    
                <span id="page_content"></span>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function load_page_content(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#page_content').html(data);
                    }
                })
            }
    
            $('.nav li').click(function(){
                var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
                load_page_content(page_id);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

There is my php code:

```
 <?php
        if ( isset($_POST["id"]) ) {
            echo '<h1>Some content</h1>';
        }
 ?>
```

I click on menu items and nothing happens. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you inspect the JS console to see if there are any errors? Inspect the network requests and see if the requests are being made?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: In the console i am getting "ajax is not a function" error, but I don't understand why. Perhaps this may have something to do with my jQuery build I am using.

Comment: Well that seems to be the root of your problem and I would look there. Your code, at first glance, looked fine to me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function. You are also attempting to place an `<h1>` tag within a `<span>` tag. I know that may be for the purposes of this question, but you shouldn't put any block tag within an inline tag.

Comment: Can the trailing comma in «id: id,» cause problems? Unsure if that are allowed

Comment: Your code works for me. There could be some internet connection problem?! or maybe strange server configuration. Just guessing. Which browser is it and which server is behind?

Comment: I use Chrome with Open server

Answer (score 0):

at first:

you shouldn't declare your function in .ready event statement

move function outside of .ready event and test your code

and at last:

you shouldn't declare your scripts outside of html tag
when you wanna use .ready event so can you can declare your codes in  tag
but when you dont wanna use it, you should define they after declaring your html tags. now you use .ready event. so you should move your scripts into head tag

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: i edited my post. recheck it again. and i hope your problem solved !