# $.ajax(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the problem even if I use the regular version of jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

html :

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="save" onclick="save()">save</button>
```

ajax function :

```
function save(){
        $.ajax() ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file.php',
            data: { name : name, content : content},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function

Comment: try

    jQuery.ajax({})

Comment: Please provide the full code.

Comment: @toHo the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: What is your environment? Wordpress? Some environments overwrite the jQuery object. What does the "$" object show in the console?

Comment: The first set of parentheses after ajax is invalid. Remove that.

Comment: @Xenology he is not using slim version.

Comment: @Xenology no because I have the problem even if I use the regular version of jquery , an this is the solution mentioned there.

Comment: @TiesonT. exactly ,thank you

Comment: @anasstahiri comment from Tieson T. is an answer

Comment: @Xenology The question you linked is indeed identical to this one, but most of the answers there are wrong. You do need the full build of jQuery, not the slim build, but the actual error is the extra `()`, as noted in [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271266/1202830).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to execute ajax() as a function, like so ajax() ({...}) this is why you get the error.

try:

```
function save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file.php',
            data: { name : name, content : content},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
}
```