# Download file and send data to flask using javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to send data from javascript to flask when the user downloaded the file,

HTML:

```
<a href="/static/{{ot[0]}}" download>
    <button type="button" class="btn" position="fixed" bottom="0px" right="0px" onclick="inc('{{ot[0]}}')">Download1</button>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function inc(argsm){

        var data1 = {'count': 1, 'name':argsm}

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/test',
            data: JSON.stringify(data1),
            dataType: 'json'

        });
    }

</script>
```

Flask

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():    
    print('test')
    rf=request.form
    print(rf)
    for key in rf.keys():
        data=key
    print(data)
    data_dic=json.loads(data)
    print(data_dic.keys())
    
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

This is not working, the ajax is not sending the data, help me to correct this, Is there any meta tag to add in head tag like connecting to ajax/jQuery link?

thanks

UPDATING ERROR -

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico 404 (NOT FOUND)
home:34 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at inc (home:34)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (home:86)
inc @ home:34
onclick @ home:86
```

Comment: Do you get any message in the browser console? Does the jquery code trigger (try printing something) or not even this?

Comment: I checked the console logs as you said, it shows-Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: is there any solution..., I even used this tag - <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
- in head tag, still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

You should import JQuery (either a hoster version or your own hosted file):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712438/9415337).

Comment: I used this in head tag, but showing same error, I also using the bootstrap, does bootstrap works with ajax?

Comment: If bootstrap and ajax are compatible, then what is the error, sir, I am new to ajax

Comment: I added the error trace for your reference, thanks