# jQuery uncaught $.ajax is not a function on flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I'm using flask and jquery for building a form and I run into an error
`(console output: "uncaught typerror $.ajax is not a function")`
I'm new to js/jquery and I tried implementing a jQuery for one of my form as such:

**register.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function() {
 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/register',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Registration Page{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
<link href="../static/css/register.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/register.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="loginForm">
    <form class="form-login">
        <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputName" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**the route method @ main.py**

```
@app.route("/register")
def registration():
    return render_template('register.html')


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    _name = request.form['inputName']
    _email = request.form['inputName']
    _password = request.form['inputPassword']

    if _name and _email and _password:
        return json.dumps({'html': '<span>All fields good!!</span>'})
    else:
        return json.dumps({'html': '<span>Enter the required fields</spans>'})
```

Now I have tried to look up other solutions in stackoverflow where people were simply getting this error by using the "jquery.slim.min.js" instead of the regular "jquery.min.js". As you can see I am calling the jquery.min.js but still get this problem. P.s. the main.py is in the root directory.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (register.js:4)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: Check page source and make sure you aren't loading another version of jQuery lower down the page  that is a ***slim*** version

Comment: Per @charlietfl : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712438/1772933

Comment: SOLVED! thanks this worked. I did not realise that I included the slim version of jQuery when adding bootstrap in my base template which conflicted with the other pages.